# Use Active Directory with Web API for SPA

Tags: c#, active-directory, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application, owin

I am building single page application and I would like to know user's identity. We have Active Directory in our intranet but I don't know much about it. I am able to use code like this to verify username and password.

```
using(PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN"))
{
  bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials("myuser", "mypassword");
}
```

In fact that is everything I need from the Active Directory side of thing. So I could create some AuthorizationFilter with this code but this would mean that username and password must be in every request. I would like to send username and password only once and then use some token for authorization. So there should be some token provider inside my server-side application.

I am building this application from scratch so I can use the latest .net technologies. I found that there are some Owin middlewares which are handling tokens, cookies and OAuth. Could anything of that help me?

Comment: upvoted because your reputation was 666. Ugh... Now you're good.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When I was searching for something completely different, I found this incredible project on CodePlex: https://angularapp.codeplex.com/ It is exactly what I was looking for.

**Update:**

The part of this app which was useful to me is the DomainUserLoginProvider

```
public class DomanUserLoginProvider : ILoginProvider
{
    public bool ValidateCredentials(string userName, string password, out ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        using (var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, _domain))
        {
            bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
            if (isValid)
            {
                identity = new ClaimsIdentity(Startup.OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType);
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName));
            }
            else
            {
                identity = null;
            }

            return isValid;
        }
    }

    public DomanUserLoginProvider(string domain)
    {
        _domain = domain;
    }

    private readonly string _domain;
}
```

LoginProvider is used in AccountController's action to verify the credentials. Also the AccessToken is created here.

```
[HttpPost, Route("Token")]
public IHttpActionResult Token(LoginViewModel login)
{
    ClaimsIdentity identity;

    if (!_loginProvider.ValidateCredentials(login.UserName, login.Password, out identity))
    {
        return BadRequest("Incorrect user or password");
    }

    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties());
    var currentUtc = new SystemClock().UtcNow;
    ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = currentUtc;
    ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = currentUtc.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));

    return Ok(new LoginAccessViewModel
    {
        UserName = login.UserName,
        AccessToken = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket)
    });
}
```

Last but not least, add the correct middleware to Owin pipeline.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    static Startup()
    {
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions();
    }

    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

    public static void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
    }
}
```

On the client side you just send the request with credentials to the Token action of AccountController and you'll get the authentication token. Save this token in browser ("Remember me" feature) and set the Angular's $http service to attach token to each request.

```
services.factory('$auth', ['$q', '$http', '$path', function ($q, $http, $path) {       
    var tokenUrl = $path('api/Account/Token');

    function setupAuth(accessToken, remember) {
        var header = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;
        delete $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = header;
        sessionStorage['accessToken'] = accessToken;
        if (remember) {
            localStorage['accessToken'] = accessToken;
        }
        return header;
    }

    var self = {};

    self.login = function(user, passw, rememberMe) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.post(tokenUrl, { userName: user, password: passw })
            .success(function (data) {
                var header = setupAuth(data.accessToken, rememberMe);
                deferred.resolve({
                    userName: data.userName,
                    Authorization: header
                });
            })
            .error(function() {
                deferred.reject();
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return self;
}]);
```

Comment: It would be nice if you took the relevant parts from the link above and explained how that site/code solves your original problem.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to a nice Spa app working with .Net, as per Jason's request could you add some context on how it helped you.

Comment: I updated answer with the code which was the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Surely the OAuth is a way to go but why don't you consider old good Forms Authentication? It fits the scenario perfectly - with a custom provider you can authenticate users in the AD and then all consecutive client requests carry the authentication cookie which can be used to authenticate server calls.

The Forms cookie in this scenario plays the role of a "token" you think of.

Comment: As you mentioned I would need to write custom membership provider where almost every method will be unimplemented. This can cause some confusions when other developers will join the project. I hate when I must say explanations like "Well, there is lots of throw new NotImplementedException() because of historical reasons." :-)

Comment: The builtin ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider will do fine, you don't have to write your own.